# Select and quit multiple processes at the same time in Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

How do I quit multiple processes in Activity Monitor at the same time? As you can see, it doesn't let me do that:

[image]
[image]

The quit button is disabled when I select more than one process in the list. Is there a way to quit more than one process at the same time? If not, why is it not allowed? (I can quit multiple processes one-by-one, but not altogether)

I'm not trying to quit Activity Monitor, it's just an example.

Comment: This is possible now: https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/macos-catalina-hidden-features/#quit-multiple-processes

Comment: Please add your "edit" as an actual Answer!

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer below to make it easier to find it.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem possible in the Activity Monitor.

However, it can be done from the Terminal like so, as long as the processes you want to quit have the same name.

To view running processes, in the Terminal

```
$ ps
```

To end processes by name

```
$ pkill -9 "nameofprocess"
```